# Dúvida simples sobre :after, :before (clearfix e etc)

Tags: html5, css3

Já vi alguns dev's usando tanto o `display:block` quanto `table` em um `after/before`, mas porque usar ? Eu acho que sei do porquê usar o `block` mas porque o `table`?

Qual a diferença?

Outra dúvida é sobre esse `*Zoom: 1;`. Por que usar?

#### Código

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
   clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
   *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Artigo em inglês que pode te ajudar http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diferença entre `block` e `table`, como o próprio nome sugere:

- `display: block`: o elemento vai ser renderizado como bloco.

```css
.exemplo{
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.classeTeste{
  display:block;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo"> Teste
 <div class="classeTeste">
        Div 1
   <div class="classeTeste">
     Div 2
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

- `display: table`: os elementos se comportam como `<table>`.

```css
.exemplo{
  display: table;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.classeTeste{
  display:table;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo"> Teste
 <div class="classeTeste">
        Div 1
   <div class="classeTeste">
     Div 2
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

A propriedade `zoom` especifica o fator de zoom inicial para a janela ou área de visualização. Pense nele como uma lupa. Veja esse [exemplo](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/arq_zoomimg/apoio_zomimg.html) e uma explicação mais detalhada nesse [Tutorial sobre Zoom](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/zoom_img.php).

`:after` e `:before` são chamados de pseuso-elementos e como o próprio nome já fala, são utilizados para inserir um determinado conteúdo antes ou depois de um determinado elemento. Lembre-se que os pseudo-elementos não suportam diversos conteúdo ao mesmo tempo e inserção de códigos HTML. Para saber mais detalhes e ver exemplos veja: [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::before) e [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

Links úteis:

- [A propriedade Display](https://codando.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/tutorial-avanado-de-css-a-propriedade-display/)
- [The zoom descriptor](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#zoom-desc)
- [CSS display](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedade-css-display.php)